# Why does Firefox Mobile (on Android only) show the same font sizes differently despite the same classes?

Tags: android, html, css, firefox

**This must be viewed in Firefox on Android to see the issue**

The following code should have all the text the same size, but on Firefox Android, the middle box text shows much larger:

VIEW IN FIREFOX ANDROID: http://jsfiddle.net/90aoz69L/embedded/result/

(To view the code, it's here: http://jsfiddle.net/90aoz69L/ )

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="boxInfo">
            <div class="boxTitle">Title 1</div>
            <div class="boxDescription">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard d</div>
        </div>
        <img src="http://www.vapor-rage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/sample.jpg" class="boxImage">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="boxInfo">
            <div class="boxTitle">Title 2</div>
            <div class="boxDescription">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and</div>
        </div>
        <img src="http://www.vapor-rage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/sample.jpg" class="boxImage">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="boxInfo">
            <div class="boxTitle">Title Number Three</div>
            <div class="boxDescription">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry'</div>
        </div>
        <img src="http://www.vapor-rage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/sample.jpg" class="boxImage">
    </div>
</div>

.boxes
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -13px;
}

.box
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 919px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.boxInfo
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 701px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.boxTitle
{
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #ba2219;
}

.boxDescription
{
    margin-top: 4px;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: 21px;
    color: #6d6d6d;
}

.boxImage
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 203px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    float: left;
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
-moz-text-size-adjust: none;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/90aoz69L/1/embedded/result/

It's due to a bug in how Firefox handles sizing font on mobile: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=707195